# React seems to be mangling variable names and then complaining they don't exist

Tags: reactjs

Over the weekend, this bug (see attached image) appears to have crept in, I'm thinkning it was a dependency  update, since the variable it's complaining about "_onAssign" does not appear once in the entire code base and the actual variable "onAssign" is defined in every case I have tested.

Is this a known result from something could I have done? (I'm still quite new to javascript and front end development, so that is enitirely possible)

extra note, this is not new code, and was working up until Friday evening, now all our builds are failing with this exact error.

[_onAssign is not used anywhere, in any of our files, so it is rightly undefined. I would like to call the function onAssign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih6Bc.png)

Comment: Please share some code with more explanation about the bug

Comment: The relevant code is in the screen shot. I am calling a function "onAssign" and react is saying "_onAssign" doesn't exist. I am happy to share whatever would be helpful, but we have hundreds of source files, what extra information would be helpful here?

Because I have absolutely no idea what could cause this, I don't really know what is relevant to share. The screen shot shows that the error and the highlighted line do not match and "onAssign" is definitely defined. I would be quite worried if I had managed to write some react code that has broken how javascript reads variable names.

Comment: unfortunatly I don't have a better explaination of the bug than:
I'm calling "onAssign" and it's saying "_onAssign" doesn't exist. I fully understand this isn't a lot to go on but it really is all I have. I'm not looking for anyone to point out a specific line of code that is wrong. I'm asking if there are any known ways that this kind of thing can come about. 
eg. "that can happen when blah blah blah" since this code has been tested, reviewed, merged and in use for a while. it's broken on our devs envs in recent deploys so could well be a dodgy dependency update. Just wondered if it's known

Answer (score 0):

You need to console log that function and comment the whole other code so you won't get any error then see what it logs in the console and from there you can find out what is causing the error .

Comment: please see screen shot. I logged the function and it is indeed defined. The traceback leads be back through a couple of function calls, none of which start with an underscore and all of which are defined and have their expected value